# Increment by 1 in while loop when string interpolation is used in Ruby

Tags: ruby

below is my scenario wherein i need to Increment by 1 in while loop when string interpolation is used in Ruby

When i do this

```
$min_value = 1
$max_value = 3
while $min_value < $max_value do
$url = "https:abcd.com?page=#{$min_value}&per_page=#{$max_value}"
puts $url
  $min_value += 1
end
```

I get result like this below, which is perfect

```
https:abcd.com?page=1&per_page=3
https:abcd.com?page=2&per_page=3
```

But i want to use the $url outside the loop as a parameter

```
$min_value = 1
$max_value = 3
$url = "https:abcd.com?page=#{$min_value}&per_page=#{$max_value}"
while $min_value < $max_value do
$test = eval('$url')
puts $test
  $min_value += 1
end
```

and i get wrong result

```
https:abcd.com?page=1&per_page=3
https:abcd.com?page=1&per_page=3
```

expected result is

```
https:abcd.com?page=1&per_page=3
https:abcd.com?page=2&per_page=3
```

how can i make this string interpolation of $min_value be increment. As my requirement is to keep the $url outside the loop as user will give this information

Comment: $url is already string, use eval($url)

Comment: I'm confused about the usage of `$max_value` - it seems to be used for both the number of items on the page **and** the loop counter. So if I want 5 items per page, I automatically get 5 pages, too?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you avoid using `eval` on a string defined with single quotes. The conventional approach is the following.

```
min_value = 1
max_value = 3
fmt = "https:abcd.com?page=%s&per_page=%s"

(min_value..max_value-1).each { |n| puts sprintf(fmt, n, max_value) }
https:abcd.com?page=1&per_page=3
https:abcd.com?page=2&per_page=3
```

The operative line could instead be written:

```
(min_value..max_value-1).each { |n| puts fmt % [n, max_value] }
```

or

```
fmt1 = fmt + "\n" 
  #=> "https:abcd.com?page=%s&per_page=%s\n" 
(min_value..max_value-1).each { |n| printf(fmt1, n, max_value) }
```

See [Kernel#sprintf](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf), [String#%](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-25) and [Kernel#printf](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Kernel.html#method-i-printf).

You should use global variables only when absolutely necessary, which often is never. Use instance variables only when a local variable will not do. I've made `min_value`, `max_value` and `fmt` all local variables because there is no suggestion by the question that their values are needed beyond the immediate task.

Generally, you should use loop structures `while`, `until` and `loop` only when the number of iterations is not known in advance. Here I've just iterated over a range.

Note that `(min_value..max_value-1)` could be replaced with `(min_value...max_value)`. I only use three-dot ranges when the end of an infinite range is to be excluded. Mixing two- and three-dot ranges (in my opinion) makes code harder to read and results in more coding errors.

Answer (score 0):

Change the $url to below:

```
$url = '"https:abcd.com?page=#{$min_value}&per_page=#{$max_value}"'
```

The reason your code is not working is because $url is already evaluated as string and you are trying to eval again. And, remove single quotes in eval method.

Final code:

```
$min_value = 1
$max_value = 3
$url = '"https:abcd.com?page=#{$min_value}&per_page=#{$max_value}"'
while $min_value < $max_value do
$test = eval($url)
puts $test
  $min_value += 1
end
```

Comment: You answer looks closed to what i am looking for.This three values will be given by user : $min_value = 1
$max_value = 3
$url = "https:abcd.com?page=#{$min_value}&per_page=#{$max_value}". I cannot change this values.the $url has to be in double quote.Can we add some code below to make it real dynamic In your case you have changed it by adding single quote. How can i keep my 3 variables intact and achieve the overall expected result?

Comment: Also, share the complete code so it will be easy to give you solution. How are you passing the user input to this method?

Comment: You should not allow the user to input thee ruby code in string variable and avoid using global variables. Why is it you can't use other solutions shared in this post? Other solution I can think of is by using string interpolation.

Answer (score 0):

### First, Refactor to Block-Local Variables

You've constructed a very non-idiomatic loop and applied some inconsistent formatting. As a result, you may be obscuring the fact that your interpolation is happening *before* you enter the loop, which means that [Kernel#eval](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Kernel.html#method-i-eval) won't resolve the way you expect even if your string were properly quoted. The string is therefore never updated.

A refactoring that avoids global variables and eval looks like this:

```rb
starting_page  = 1
items_per_page = 3

starting_page.upto(items_per_page) do |page|
  url = "https://abcd.com?page=#{page}&per_page=#{items_per_page}"
  puts url
end
```

This yields your expected results:

> ```
> https://abcd.com?page=1&per_page=3
> https://abcd.com?page=2&per_page=3
> https://abcd.com?page=3&per_page=3
> ```

By defining a block-local variable (e.g. *page*) you also prevent unintended changes outside the block formed by [Integer#upto](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Integer.html#method-i-upto). Understanding scope gates in Ruby has a steep learning curve, but it's often very helpful in avoiding subtle (or not-so-subtle) bugs in your code.

### Next, Define a Format String Outside Your Loop

If you want to move the *url* variable outside the block, you will still need to generate a new string inside the loop. Eval is not ideal for this, although it can work if you fix your quoting. A better approach is to use [Kernel#printf](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Kernel.html#method-i-printf) or [Kernel#sprintf](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf) with a format string, depending on whether you want the output on an IO object or as a return value. For example:

```rb
starting_page  = 1
items_per_page = 3
format_string  = "https://abcd.com?page=%d&per_page=%d\n"

starting_page.upto(items_per_page) do |page|
  printf format_string, page, items_per_page
end
```

This will print the same values to standard output as the loop with interpolation, but the string holding the *format* of the URL is now defined outside the loop while the `%d` placeholders in each string are replaced at runtime.